# estimating alpha beta for beta binomial using VGAM R package

Tags: r, parameters

A similar question was asked about alpha beta estimation for beta binomial distribution.

I understand the answers there; my question is more about the error I am getting.

My data is:

```
r1 = c(3, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 0, 4,2, 4, 6)
r2 = c(5, 1, 0, 1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 1, 7)
z = cbind(r1,r2)
fit = vglm(z ~ 1, betabinomialff, trace = TRUE)
```

I get the following error message:

```
VGLM    linear loop  1 :  loglikelihood = -17.569074
VGLM    linear loop  2 :  loglikelihood = -16.796047
VGLM    linear loop  3 :  loglikelihood = -16.556079
VGLM    linear loop  4 :  loglikelihood = -16.489902
VGLM    linear loop  5 :  loglikelihood = -16.486634
VGLM    linear loop  6 :  loglikelihood = -16.486634
Taking a modified step....................

Warning messages:
1: In checkwz(wz, M = M, trace = trace, wzepsilon = control$wzepsilon) :
  22 diagonal elements of the working weights variable 'wz' have been            replaced by 1.819e-12
2: In vglm.fitter(x = x, y = y, w = w, offset = offset, Xm2 = Xm2,  :
```

iterations terminated because half-step sizes are very small
    3: In vglm.fitter(x = x, y = y, w = w, offset = offset, Xm2 = Xm2,  :
  some quantities such as z, residuals, SEs may be inaccurate due to convergence at a half-step

How do I get alpha beta estimates for a beta binomial model, without running into this error? I am not very familiar with all details of using the vglm function, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks!